# Inserting every 'n' page of several pdf files

Tags: pdfpages

I have 3 pdf files (`a.pdf`, `b.pdf` and `c.pdf`) with 50 images per file. I need to insert every page of each pdf one by one (3 in a row). **Not all pages** from first pdf and all from another, but one page from `a.pdf`, one from `b.pdf` and `c.pdf`

Desired output would be to have one document with pages: 
1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c....50a, 50b, 50c

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge[nup=1x3]
{a.pdf, 1,2,3,
b.pdf, 1,2,3,
c.pdf, 1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it will be easier to simply write a script to generate the 50 simple `\includepdfmerge` lines.

Comment: good point but how to insert a pdf in each position of `nup=1x3` ? Do I need to create a table with `\includepdf` for 150 images?

Comment: Good question. Another solution, would be to first merge the three documents in the right order so the new doc has a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2, etc. And then run the nup on that file.

Comment: See my longer comment below

Comment: Maybe it is better to solve this with a tool like `pdftk`?

Comment: In Linux, I'd use [pdfjam](http://go.warwick.ac.uk/pdfjam), a script that uses the LaTeX facilities to shuffle PDF files around (and do jobs as this one). It is unwidely because of it's generality, but doing what you ask for isn't easy to describe in the first place. Or write a script in Perl of Python to mash up a LaTeX file that does what you want. LaTeX is nice as markup, but severely lacking as a general purpose scripting language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a comment, as it is a bit too long for a normal comment.

Does

```
\includepdfmerge[nup=1x3]{a.pdf, 1,b.pdf, 1, c.pdf, 1}
\includepdfmerge[nup=1x3]{a.pdf, 2,b.pdf, 2, c.pdf, 2} 
...
```

work? Because that could be done via a simple latex loop

---

This seems to work

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach\n in{1,...,5}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=1x3]{a.pdf,\n,b.pdf,\n,c.pdf,\n}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea to have similar output but with pdf files with different number of pages? For example, `a` contains 4 pages and `b` contains only 3. So I'd like to do the loop from 1 to 4. But I got an error since `b` does not contain page 4.

Comment: I do not know. Try asking another question and ask for a test to see if a specific page in a PDF exists.

Answer (score 1):

This extends the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260847/16967) of daleif to add the automatic retrieval of the number of pages of the included document, when pdfTeX in PDF mode is used.
The command `\pdflastximagepages` returns the number of pages of the previously included PDF document right before calling `\pdflastximagepages`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\sbox0{\includegraphics{a.pdf}}
\edef\PagesA{\number\pdflastximagepages}

\foreach\n in{1,...,\PagesA}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=1x3]{a.pdf,\n,b.pdf,\n,c.pdf,\n}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! What do you mean by *of the latest included*? In your example, you choose `a` to compute the number of pages. But the ideal should be to use the file which has less pages?

Comment: @Sigur I have changed it to "previously included", maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: So, it means the one inside the `\sbox0`? I think so.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, the purpose of `\sbox0` is just to throw away the included graphics, because at this time only the number of pages is interesting.

Comment: From where comes `\pdflastximagepages`? I'd like to know what else information we can extract from the pdf files. Maybe dates, authors, and so on.

Comment: @Sigur As I have written, it's a primitive of pdfTeX. Meta data are not available. Try LuaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension of the [solution proposed by @Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262471/14757).

It works for two files (can be adapted for more) even if they have different number of pages.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}
\edef\PagesA{\number\pdflastximagepages}
\sbox1{\includegraphics{old.pdf}}
\edef\PagesB{\number\pdflastximagepages}
\newcounter{Min}
\newcounter{Max}
\setcounter{Min}{\minof{\PagesA}{\PagesB}}
\setcounter{Max}{\maxof{\PagesA}{\PagesB}}



\foreach\n in{1,...,\theMin}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n,old.pdf,\n}
}
\ifnum\theMin=\PagesA
  \addtocounter{Min}{1}
  \foreach\n in{\theMin,...,\theMax}{
    \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{old.pdf,\n}
  }
\else
  \addtocounter{Min}{1}
  \foreach\n in{\theMin,...,\theMax}{
    \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n}
  }
\fi
\end{document}
```