# Insert pdf pages side by side

Tags: pdfpages, foreach

I have two versions (A4 size) of a document: `new.pdf` and `old.pdf`.

I'd like to share with co-authors a pdf with pages side by side, so should be easy to compare the changes in the output.

[Here there is a partial solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260847/14757) which works well **only if the files have the same number of pages**.

[An extension of that partial solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262471/14757) is proposed and makes use of `\pdflastximagepages` to compute the number of pages of a previous inserted pdf file. So this number can be used for the loop.

Since my pdf files could have **different numbers of pages**, the solutions cited above don't work.

So, my idea is:

**1.**  compute the number of pages for both files.

```
\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}
\edef\PagesA{\number\pdflastximagepages}

\sbox1{\includegraphics{old.pdf}}
\edef\PagesB{\number\pdflastximagepages}
```

**2.** define the numbers `\Min=min(\PagesA,\PagesB)` and `\Max=max(\PagesA,\PagesB)`

**3.** from `1` to `\Min` insert pages from both files using

```
\foreach\n in{1,...,\Min}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n,old.pdf,\n}
}
```

**4.** finally, test if `\Min=\PagesA` or `\Min=\PagesB`.

**4.1** if `\Min=\PagesA` then use

```
\foreach\n in{\Min+1,...,\Max}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{old.pdf,\n} % old is on the right hand side
}
```

**4.2** if `\Min=\PagesB` then use

```
\foreach\n in{\Min+1,...,\Max}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n} % new is on the left hand side
}
```

**My question is:** how to implement (4)?

**M(W)E**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}
\edef\PagesA{\number\pdflastximagepages}
\sbox1{\includegraphics{old.pdf}}
\edef\PagesB{\number\pdflastximagepages}
%\edef\Min{}
%\edef\Max{}

\foreach\n in{1,...,\Min}{
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n,old.pdf,\n}
}
\foreach\n in{\Min+1,...,\Max}{
%% test here to decide if new or old should be used
  \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{??.pdf,\n}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The number of pages can be retrieved by `\pdflastximagepages` (pdfTeX in PDF mode), see my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262471/16967) to question [Inserting every 'n' page of several pdf files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260841/16967).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I edited. Not I think that the post could be reopened.

Comment: A possible solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262484/14757 but I'm not sure if it is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution than [the one mentioned before in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260841/inserting-every-n-page-of-several-pdf-files/262484#262484). The differences are:

- Only computes the maximum of the page numbers. (The minimum is not used.)
- Tests in every iteration step (in the for loop over the pages) if there are two ore only one page to be included.
- Takes into account if single pages should be placed on the left or the right.

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages,pgffor}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}
\edef\PagesNew{\number\pdflastximagepages}
\sbox1{\includegraphics{old.pdf}}
\edef\PagesOld{\number\pdflastximagepages}
\newcounter{Max}
\setcounter{Max}{\maxof{\PagesNew}{\PagesOld}}

\foreach\n in{1,...,\theMax}{
    \ifnum\n>\PagesNew
        \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1,openright]{old.pdf,\n}
    \else
        \ifnum\n>\PagesOld
            \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n}
        \else
            \includepdfmerge[nup=2x1]{new.pdf,\n, old.pdf, \n}
        \fi
    \fi
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very elegant. I tried first to make the test inside the loop but I don't know why I felt that it could use more memory. Anyway, I liked it.